# Looking for people who've been to both Tallinn, Estonia and Brasov, Romania

Tags: architecture, cities, tallinn

I'm interested in nice medieval cities. I can go to Tallinn or Brasov and I'm unsure what to choose. I enjoy architecture and a nice city around it.

Where should I go first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tallinn.

Brasov was nice and in the mountains and has wildlife (bears) to see occasionally, but there's not that much there.  The usual town sites.  It didn't feel like a medieval city.

Tallinn on the other hand has arguably Europe's best preserved medieval city.  The old town still has most of its walls around, and there are basically no new buildings within - some have been repurposed, but that's it.  And in May, they have their annual medieval festival and it feels like you're back in time.  With great old pubs, elk soup, bear steaks and honey mead, you get the food to boot, and the castle, churches, walls and town square - it's really fantastic.  Pedestrian only as well!